# I try to change a hover function into a click function

Tags: jquery, click, hover

i am a newbie : /

I've found this code and just wanted to change "hover" into "click". Which does not work unfortunately. Then i read a similar problem where someone suggested to insert `obj.on('click', [selector,] function()` instead of hover.

This doesn't work too.

So, how can i make this code work just on a click instead hovering? Below is the original code. Would be great if someone could help out.

```
(function($) {
     $.fn.hoverexpand = function(options) {
     var defaults = {
       minHeight: '100px',           
       collapsedClass: 'expand-me',  
 event
       hoverTime: 250                /
     };
     var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

     return this.each(function() {
       var $obj = $(this);
       var origHeight = $obj.css('height');
       var timer = null;

       if( parseInt(origHeight) > parseInt(options.minHeight)) {
         $obj.css({
           height: options.minHeight,
           overflow: 'hidden'
         }).addClass(options.collapsedClass);

         $obj.hover(
           function() {  // click not mouseover
             if(!timer) {
               timer = window.setTimeout(function() { 
                 $obj.animate({height: origHeight }, 250).removeClass(options.collapsedClass);       //expand
                 timer = null;
               }, options.hoverTime);
             }
           },
           function() {  // mouseout
             if(timer) {
               window.clearTimeout(timer);
               timer = null;
             } else {
               $obj.animate({height: options.minHeight}, 250).addClass(options.collapsedClass);    //contract
             }
           }
         );
       }
     });   }; })(jQuery);
```

Comment: change $obj.hover to $obj.click

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you want to include a block of code in your question, please indent it by four spaces, or select it and click the `{}` button. (Don't use `>` at the start of each line, that creates a block quote of text, not code.) You can also include code inline by quoting it with the ` character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) which takes a list of functions to call on alternating clicks..

So instead of `$obj.hover` use `$obj.toggle`

Comment: Big thank you for all of you. .toggle() works nice.
I'll keep that hint with the proper block code in mind. sorry for that.

Comment: Hello, i have an additional question: 

Is it possible to prevent this code from overriding the (url) link-functionality? 

I mean it makes sense, because you toggle it open and closed. But what's to do if you have a or multiple links in a container?

The pointer recognizes the correct link, but when I press.. well, yeah it closes the container o.O

Comment: @peter In the second function change the `else` to `else if (obj.is(':not(a)'))`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hover (which takes 2 functions as arguments  - mouseover and mouseout) you could listen for the `mouseout` and the `click` events separately like this:

```
$obj.on('mouseout', function(){
  //do things
});

$obj.on('click', function(){
  //do things
});
```

(see http://api.jquery.com/on/ for more details)

Comment: Just in addition.. i am impressed of those quick and helpful responds here. That's really great! Thanks again ^^

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `.hover()` (uses mouseenter/mouseleave) function with:

```
$obj.on({
    click : function() {  // click
        if(!timer) {
          timer = window.setTimeout(function() { 
            $obj.animate({height: origHeight }, 250).removeClass(options.collapsedClass);       //expand
            timer = null;
          }, options.hoverTime);
        }
     },
     mouseleave: function() {  // mouseout
        if(timer) {
          window.clearTimeout(timer);
          timer = null;
        } else {
          $obj.animate({height: options.minHeight}, 250).addClass(options.collapsedClass);    //contract
        }
     }
});
```